# i don't know $delete in vim script

Tags: vim

I'm learning vim script [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html).
but, I have reached a deadlock.

```
:let save_ic = &ic
:set noic
:/The Start/,$delete
:let &ic = save_ic
```

I don't know what **$delete** means.

Is this an option?

Please tell me what it is.
And, please inform the document related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interesting line

```
:/The Start/,$delete
```

means issuing a command `:delete` to a range of lines, similar to what `:1,10delete`would do. In this case, the first line in the range is the next line where pattern `/The Start/` matches, and the last line in range is the last line in the file, `$`.

For clarity, you can write the command with a space between `$` and the command `:delete`.

You can read through `:h range`to see other options. Here is another presentation of command ranges: [The Vim Ranger](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.fi/2012/02/vim-ranger.html).

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question now that you know the answer. The context (that it is part of range) is important: `:$delete` is also a proper command, to delete just the last line!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I also found this article. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges